# Get a reference of current proxy in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, aop, spring-aop

Anyone know how to get a reference of the current proxy in a class with `@Service` annotation in Spring boot?

`AopContext.currentProxy()` doesn't work, it says that need to set `exposeProxy` to true, but I've no idea how to do it with Spring boot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a [bug](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-10454) related but it was resolved on Spring 4.3.1.

Now you can set `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(exposeProxy=true)`